# Sorting a subset of a list of strings

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting

I have a list of strings containing the column names of a specific dataframe, and I want to sort a subset of the list so that it follows a certain standard format.

Specifically, to clarify things here is an example :

Input list :

```
array = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2010 b', '2010 c', '2011 a', '2011 b', '2011 c']
```

Desired output :

```
array = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2011 a', '2010 b', '2011 b', '2010 c', '2011 c']
```

In other words there is a subset of the array that should be left untouched (ie var1 var2 var3) and another subset that should be sorted **first by the element after the whitespace** and then **by the element preceding whitespace**.

How could this be done efficiently ?

Comment: Can `'var...'` appear anywhere in the list, or is it always the first n items?

Comment: It is assumed to be the first n items indeed.

Comment: How is the "subset" specified? Is it `array[n:]`, i.e., input to the task is `array` and `n`?

Comment: Yep, it's the case.
Tbh, this was an additional step I had to do because of my laziness.
To put some context : the `var ...` columns are actually time series data `['2010',' 2011', ...]` and i performed some calculations on them, so for each year I was using all the sime series to do some calculations and then storing these calculations in a new column, so when I was looping through the columns and was at the column 2010, I performed the different calculations that yielded the columns '2010 a', '2010 b', '2010 c', and appended them to the end of the dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case:

```
array = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2010 b', '2010 c', '2011 a', '2011 b', '2011 c']

array[3:] = sorted(array[3:], key=lambda s:s.split()[::-1])
```

the various parts of this should be straightforward. Replace the fourth element onwards with the rest of the sorted list, according to a custom key. This custom key will split the element on any whitespace, and then compare them based on the splits in reverse order (last split takes priority).

Comment: And if `'var...'` can appear anywhere?

Comment: ^^^ that would be a good challenge.  ;-)    This is not quite flexible...

Answer (score 3):

This solution assumes that `'var...'` (or whatever you want to leave untouched) can appear anywhere.

Extract the elements you want to sort, remember their indexes, sort them, then put them back:

```
lst = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2010 b', '2010 c', '2011 a', '2011 b', '2011 c']

where, what = zip(*((i, x) for i, x in enumerate(lst) if not x.startswith('var')))
what = sorted(what, key=lambda x: x.split()[::-1])

for i, x in zip(where, what):
    lst[i] = x

print(lst)
# ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2011 a', '2010 b', '2011 b', '2010 c', '2011 c']
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
def sort_second(string_list: list):
    """
    Sort a list of strings according to the value after the string
    """
    output = []
    sorting_dict = {}
    for string in string_list:
        try:
            # split the first and the second values
            value, key = string.split(" ")
            try:
                # something with the same key has already been read in
                # sort this value into a list with the other value(s) from
                # the same key
                insort_left(sorting_dict[key], value)
            except:
                # nothing else with the same key has been read in yet
                sorting_dict[key] = [value]
        except:
            # split didn't work therefore, must be single value entry 
            output.append(string)

    # for loop sorts second key
    for key in sorted(sorting_dict.keys()):
        for value in sorting_dict[key]:
            # list contains values sorted according to the first key
            output.append(" ".join((value, key)))

    return output
```

I'd need to run some tests but this does the job and should be reasonably quick.

I have used dict as opposed to ordereddict because ordereddict is implemented in python rather than C

I think O(n) is nlog(n) but I'm not sure what kind of sort `sorted()` uses so it may be worse (if it is I'm fairly sure there will be something else to do the job more efficiently)

Edit:
I accidentally stated the time complexity as log(n) in the original post, as Kelly pointed out this is impossible. The correct time complexity (as edited above) is O(n) = nlog(n)

Comment: While I have done this with an eye to performance I am by no means an expert so I could be a way off the ball. Though frankly if execution speed is your primary concern then you probably shouldn't be coding in python.

Comment: "O(n) is log(n)"? I can't make sense of that ...

Comment: time taken for n objects is proportional to log(n)

Comment: No it's not. In log(n), you can't even look at all of them.

Comment: apologies I meant to put nlog(n) I'll correct it

Comment: "O(n) = nlog(n)" still doesn't make sense, though. Its not clear how to even read that.

Comment: number of elements multiplied by the log of the number of elements. It's high school maths

Comment: That part is clear but "O(n) = f(n)" doesn't make sense. "f(n) = O(n)" is established notation, but even then, the function actually needs to be in O(n), so even "nlog(n) = O(n)" would be wrong.

Comment: No it isn't. The parts of the function that depend on the number of items in the array are reading in the items to the dictionary O(n) = n and the binary search's which are log(n) as they do not need to check all of the entries (seeing as how they half the size of the list to search with each iteration)

Comment: As one is nested inside the other they multiply to give O(n) = nlog(n)

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
array = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2010 b', '2010 c', '2011 a', '2011 b', '2011 c']

desired = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', '2010 a', '2011 a', '2010 b', '2011 b', '2010 c', '2011 c']
```

Three easy ways.

First, with a `split` and find if there is a second element:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda e: "" if len(e.split())==1 else e.split()[1])==desired
True
```

Or use `partition` and use the last element:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda e: e.partition(' ')[2])==desired
True
```

Or with a regex to remove the first element:

```
>>> sorted(array, key=lambda e: re.sub(r'^\S+\s*','', e))==desired
True
```

All three rely on the fact that Python's sort is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).